# Strange -1.#IND error in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, division, operator-precedence

Here's a weird calculation error in VB.NET. I've simplified my problem to the following. I can write:

```
Console.WriteLine(-0.78125 ^ 2.5)
```

and get `-0.53947966093944366`.

But if I change it to `Console.WriteLine((-0.78125 + 0) ^ 2.5)`, I get `-1.#IND`.

Or, if it try:

```
Dim D as Double = -0.78125
Console.WriteLine(D ^ 2.5)
```

I also get `-1.#IND`.

I can only get the calculation to return a result if I use a single literal number in the expression, but when I use a variable of any data type I get `-1.#IND`.

I've read the other posts that explaining "-1.#IND", but they indicate that one of the numbers in the expression is [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), which is not the case here. Why is this happening?

Comment: Write .NET code instead, use Math.Pow()

Answer (score 7):

You can figure out what's going on by trying following:

```
Console.WriteLine(-1 ^ 0.5)
```

It prints `-1`, but in fact it is the same as `sqrt(-1)` which does not have a result in Real numbers. That's weird, isn't it? So what's going on here?

`^` has higher precedence than `-`, so `-1 ^ 0.5` is actually `-(1 ^ 0.5)`. That's why it prints `-1`.

You can check the precedence list here: [Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx)

The same happens with your code. `-0.78125 ^ 2.5` is actually interpreted as `-(0.78125 ^ 2.5)` which is valid, but if you do `(-0.78125 + 0) ^ 2.5` (or even `(-0.78125) ^ 2.5`) it's not valid anymore, because it would require calculating square root from negative value. That's why you're getting `NaN` (or `-1#IND`).